# Unit Testing JsonResult anonymous type in .Net Core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, jsonresult

**UPdated: Solution at bottom**

In .net core JsonResult does not have a "Data" property.
Many of the existing answers us that property to retrieve the needed values for unit testing.

I can't seem to wrap my head around the problem here:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetIndividualPerformanceMetrics(string npi)
    {
        var metrics = new List<PhysicianMetric>();
        var overallRank = new OverallPhysicianRank();
        var userNPI = User.GetSingleClaimValueByType(Constants.ClaimTypes.Npi);
        npi = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(npi) ? userNPI : npi;
        if (npi != null)
        {

            if (await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "IsMetricSupportTeam")
                || User.GetAllClaimsByType(Constants.ClaimTypes.Npi).Any(n => n.Value == npi))
            {
                metrics = (await _physicianMetrics.GetAllByNPIAsync(npi)).ToList();
            }
        }
        return Json(new { metrics });
    }
```

And in my unit test I'm doing the following:

```
            _physicianMetrics.Setup(pm => pm.GetAllByNPIAsync(validNPI))
            .ReturnsAsync(new List<PhysicianMetric>(){_physicianMetric});

        var anonymousDefinition = new { metrics = new List<PhysicianMetric>() };

        //Act
        var result = await (performanceMetricsController.GetIndividualPerformanceMetrics(validNPI)) as JsonResult;
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(result.Value.ToString(), anonymousDefinition);
        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(validNPI, obj.metrics[0].NPI);
```

The JsonResult is returning with the mocked repository values, but I can't seem to write the test so that I can ensure the JsonResult data is the data returned by the repository query. The deserialization fails with the following error:

"Invalid character after parsing property name. Expected ':' but got: =. Path '', line 1, position 10. "

I just need to validate the JsonResult values.

Please Help.

**Solution**:  (Thanks Chris Pratt)

I didn't realize that the JsonResult had not yet serialized the object, and that the JsonResult.Value was the pure anonymous type.  I just used reflection to call out the list of objects that I needed and was good to go:

```
        var result = await (performanceMetricsController.GetIndividualPerformanceMetrics(validNPI)) as JsonResult;
        var metrics = result.Value.GetType().GetProperty("metrics")?.GetValue(result.Value, null) as List<PhysicianMetric>;

        //Assert
        _physicianMetrics.Verify(pm => pm.GetAllByNPIAsync(validNPI), Times.Once);
        Assert.AreEqual(validNPI, metrics[0]?.NPI);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. You say that you're able to tell that the `JsonResult` has the correct values, but then you say you can't seem to write a test that shows this? How do you know that the values are correct? If you can see that they are, then you should be able to assert it just as easily.

Comment: Also, FWIW, you should probably be integration testing this controller action rather than unit testing. Setting up a ton of mocks to satisfy all the dependencies a controller action has, adds less certainty that the test is actually a valid one. If could fail because you simply didn't mock something right, or it could actually pass, but you could still get errors when dealing with a more real-world scenario. I'd recommend using the test host, instead, which would coincidentally also make testing the JSON return easier.

Comment: @Chris Pratt I can see the values when I debug the test and hover over the objects.  Getting those values into something I can compare in an assert, however, has been troubling.

Comment: That's what I'm not understanding. As you drill down into the object explorer, you'd simply take the same path to access it via code. Can you be more specific about where exactly things are going awry?

Comment: result has the property "Value"  This contains the anonymous object as declared in the "return Json(new {metrics}) line of the controller method. I'm not able to cast the value into anything syntactically usable.  I'm calling JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType with the declared definition, but it false to parse.

Comment: Edited Question to reflect error received when attempting to deserialize the JsonResult.Value

Comment: `Value` is the object itself, not JSON. The serialization happens after the result is passed back to the request pipeline. You just need to cast it to something usable.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks!  I didn't know that the result wasn't already serialized. I really wasn't sure what was going on.  It's resolved now, and I'll update the question.